# Apply trait bounds to associated type

Tags: rust

Let's say I have a trait like this:

```rust
trait InternalError {
    fn internal(error: String) -> Self;
}
```

If I want to use this in a function, I can do so like this:

```rust
struct MyU16(pub u16);

fn my_try_from<E: InternalError>(value: u32) -> Result<MyU16, E> {
    if value < u16::MAX as u32 {
        Ok(MyU16(value as u16))
    } else {
        Err(E::internal("invalid".to_string()))
    }
}
```

[This works just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc1b2eeff7600697335c2352906e994d).

Now imagine instead of using my own function, I want to use `TryFrom`:

```rust
impl<E: InternalError> TryFrom<u32> for MyU16 {
    type Error = E;

    fn try_from(value: u32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if value < u16::MAX as u32 {
            Ok(MyU16(value as u16))
        } else {
            Err(E::internal("invalid".to_string()))
        }
    }
}
```

This however does not work. I have tried various different ways to phrase this, but I can't figure out how to say "this TryFrom impl, in the error case, returns something that impls InternalError".

How can I do this properly?

Comment: What's the reason `InternalError` is a trait as opposed to an `enum`? If it were `enum InternalError` then it'd be a concrete type and you wouldn't need the generics that are causing you heartburn.

Comment: As written, `Error` needs to be a single concrete type. You could try a boxed trait object: `type Error = Box<dyn InternalError>`.

Comment: It's hard to explain without more code but in short, I have different functions that could call into my TryFrom impl that themselves all return different error types. This bound ensures that only functions that themselves return errors that could be InternalErrors can call this function. It then allows the function to build an instance of the caller's error through the trait function.

Comment: If I have a bound like `type = Box<dyn InternalError` (and ensure that InternalError is object safe, which I can), it doesn't work because I now can't call `E::internal`, since `E` is not the error type, it's a Box.

Comment: Instead of making a generic `try_from`, how about using a regular function that returns a fixed error type, and then use [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) to map the error into a different internal one in each of the callers?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now but as I develop further, I'm writing functions where the context for which error type to use is deeper in the call stack (as in, a function may return one of multiple types) so it isn't possible to figure this out from the caller (unless ofc I return something at runtime, like a code, which I want to avoid).

Comment: What about impl `From<String>` for your error types so that it can be automatically cast to the type you want through `?` operator?

Comment: Or return an `InternalError` and impl `From<InternalError>` for your error types if `From<String>` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

> this TryFrom impl, in the error case, returns something that impls InternalError

`TryFrom` wants to know at compile time what error type is returned. You seem to want to decide on the type at runtime.

Let's assume `FirstError` and `SecondError` both implement `InternalError`.

In this case

```rust
impl TryFrom<u32> for MyU16 {
    type Error = FirstError;

    fn try_from(value: u32) -> Result<Self, FirstError> {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

Would compile, but of course `try_from` can only ever return `FirstError`.

If you want to decide at runtime between `FirstError` and `SecondError` however. The associated error **type** (not trait) needs to be able to hold both.

```rust
impl TryFrom<u32> for MyU16 {
    type Error = Box<dyn InternalError>;

    fn try_from(value: u32) -> Result<Self, Box<dyn InternalError>> {
        /*...*/
        Box::new(FirstError::internal("invalid".to_string()))
    }
}
```

This also gives a hint of why `enum`s are the idiomatic way to represent errors in Rust: Usually you do know at compile time what **could** go wrong, but you do not yet know what actually **does** go wrong (if anything). Actual errors occurring you only know at runtime. Therfore it is a good idea to have the type being able to represent a set of potential error, and the instance to be a specific error.

An `enum`eration fits that bill and makes it clear for the user what could go wrong and in many situations allows you to create the error without an additional heap allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't compile is there is a rule that the type parameter in the `impl` declaration has to appear in the *implementing type* (`impl<T> Foo<T>`) or the *implemented trait* (`impl<T> MyTrait<T> for Foo`). You can't just write `impl<T> for Foo` and only mention `T` again inside the `impl` block.

As the expanded error suggests, there is a workaround introducing a phantom type to the implementing type, but you might not like how it makes your code look:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct MyU16<T>(pub u16, PhantomData<T>);

impl<E: InternalError> TryFrom<u32> for MyU16<E> {
    type Error = E;

    fn try_from(value: u32) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if value < u16::MAX as u32 {
            Ok(MyU16(value as u16, PhantomData))
        } else {
            Err(E::internal("invalid".to_string()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case the actual thing I'm returning here is an enum, I just used a struct for the example, so it's not easy to use PhantomData.  It sounds like the easiest thing to do here really is just to give up on using the trait and use a bare function.